# How to fill in weeks from date in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, gantt-chart, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to build a time-schedule with Google Sheets. As you can see on the image below, column A is for tasks. Column B is the beginning of a task, Column C is the end of a task and column D is the calculated days the task is estimated to take:

[image: Sample data]

What I want is to plot the weeks in the columns from E to L, depending on the number of weeks required.

As you can see, column E is week 39 2015.

How can I get spreadsheet to fill in the weeks automatically with a color, according to start and end dates?

Comment: Fill with what ? 0s and 1s?

Comment: I would like to fill it with a color, so that it will make a kind of Gantt Chart.

Comment: So if the week exist in the range color it with green otherwise nothing?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add continual formatting with the formula:

```
=AND(VALUE(MID(E$1,5,5))<=WEEKNUM($C2),VALUE(MID(E$1,5,5))>=WEEKNUM($B2))
```

for the cell E2. 
Choose the color you desire.
 Then use the format brush for all all the cells.

Comment: Should I add the formula you put in E2?

Comment: Adding the formula to the cell will just return True or False. If you wish to change the color you have to use conditional formatting with the formula. If you have difficulties to do that I will add instructions to my answer.

Comment: I tried to right-click --> choose conditional formatting --> adapted formula --> inserted your formula. Then I got the message "Invalid formula"?

Comment: You have to be on cell E2 when you are doing this.

Comment: I am, but get the answer "Invalid Formula"?

Comment: Lets start from the basics. if you are adding this to e2: =AND(VALUE(MID(E$1,5,5))<=WEEKNUM($C2),VALUE(MID(E$1,5,5))>=WEEKNUM($B2))  is it returning #value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90530/discussion-between-tommy-otzen-and-balinti).